# Java Auto-"Refresh" Function

Tags: java, swing, colors, jpanel, refresh

I am changing the color of a JPanel using a `setColor` and `getColor` method.

Now I want to change it so you don't have to click the `getColor` Button in a function which is calling the `getColor` all 100ms.

But after a lot of usage of Google I simply can't find a way to do so.

Hope you can help me with this.

### Code

```
package tutorial9a;

/**
 *
 * @author HiveMind
 */
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Timer;

// 1. Import 
// hier fehlt Code: zwei Imports
// hier fehlt Code: eine Implementierung
public class Tutorial09a extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private static int st_fensternummer = 0;
    private int fensternummer = 0;
    // global fuer addActionListener
    JButton bnCreate = new JButton("create1");
    JButton bnsetBlue = new JButton("setBlue");
    JButton bnsetRed = new JButton("setRed");
    JButton bnsetGreen = new JButton("setGreen");
    JButton bnClose = new JButton("Close");
    JPanel panelBn = new JPanel();
    Farbe farbe = Farbe.getInstance();
    
    

    public Tutorial09a(Farbe farbe) {
        this.farbe = farbe;
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setGUI();
    }

    private void setGUI() {
        setSize(800, 100);
        fensternummer = ++st_fensternummer;
        setTitle("Tutorial09a: " + fensternummer);

        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        panelBn.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
        panelBn.add(bnCreate);
        panelBn.add(bnsetBlue);
        panelBn.add(bnsetRed);
        panelBn.add(bnsetGreen);
        panelBn.add(bnClose);


        panelBn.setBackground(farbe.color);
        // hier fehlt Code: eine Registrierung

        this.getContentPane().add(panelBn, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        setFonts(getContentPane(), 18);

        bnCreate.addActionListener(this);
        bnsetBlue.addActionListener(this);
        bnsetRed.addActionListener(this);
        bnsetGreen.addActionListener(this);
        bnClose.addActionListener(this);
    } // setGUI

    private void setFonts(Container cont, int size) {
        for (int i = 0; i < cont.getComponentCount(); i++) {
            Component c = cont.getComponent(i);
            if (c instanceof JPanel) {
                setFonts((JPanel) c, size);
            } else {
                c.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, size));
            }
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == bnCreate) {
            create_click();
        }
        if (e.getSource() == bnsetBlue) {
            setBlue_click();
        }
        if (e.getSource() == bnsetRed) {
            setRed_click();
        }
        if (e.getSource() == bnsetGreen) {
            setGreen_click();
        }

        if (e.getSource() == bnClose) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    private void create_click() {
        Tutorial09a frame = new Tutorial09a(farbe);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocation((int) (Math.random() * getWidth()), (int) (Math.random() * getHeight()));
    }

    private void setBlue_click() {
        farbe.color = Color.BLUE;
        getColor_click();
    }

    private void setRed_click() {
        farbe.color = Color.RED;
        getColor_click();
    }

    private void setGreen_click() {
        farbe.color = Color.GREEN;
        getColor_click();
    }

    private void getColor_click() {
        panelBn.setBackground(farbe.color);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Farbe farbe2 = new Farbe();
        Tutorial09a frame = new Tutorial09a(farbe2);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
    }
} // Tutorial09a

// hier fehlt Code: eine Ableitung
class Farbe {

    private static Farbe instance = new Farbe();

    public Farbe() {
        color = Color.BLUE;
    }

    public static Farbe getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
    public Color color;
    // hier fehlt Code: eine Methode
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide some code ?

Comment: So you want to have a task running periodically (every 100ms) to call a `getColor` method?

Comment: Here is the Link to the full code. I am looking for a way to call the getColor_click() every 100ms [link](http://pastebin.com/NxCLScP5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) class.

Comment: It is best to link to the latest version of the JavaDocs. I have edited your answer to point to J2SE 7. For tips on getting a link to the latest docs, see [point 2 of advantages](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7090875).  Please roll it back if you disagree. Otherwise, vote for the RFE.  ;)